# Meteor - Passing an object to template but it doesnt display data

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to create a blog(with meteor) that will have different categories for posts, then trying to create a page that displays all categories and the titles off posts in those categories.

This is the Javascript code I am using.

```
Template.categories.cats = function(){
    reviews =   Reviews.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
    opinions = PointlessOpinions.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
    days = DaysInTheLife.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
    return {reviews: reviews,opinions: opinions, days: days};  
}
```

This is the HTML template

```
<template name = "categories">
   <div class = "container">
    <h1>Reviews</h1>
     {{#each reviews}}
      <h2> {{title}}</h2>
     {{/each}}
   </div>
   <div class = "container">
     <h1>A day in the life</h1>
     {{#each days}}
       <a href="/post/{{this._id}}">
         <h2> {{title}}</h2>
       </a>
     {{/each}}
   </div>
   <div class = "container">
    <h1>Pointless Opinions</h1>
    {{#each opinions}}
    <a href="/post/{{this._id}}">
       <h2> {{title}}</h2>
     </a>
     {{/each}}
   </div>
</template>
```

I have tested to see if the Collections have the data and it seems so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it like this:

```
Template.categories.helpers({
    reviews: function (){
        return Reviews.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
    },
    //and the rest of the helpers to use in that template
});
```

Comment: As I know `#each` supports only `Array`, so it should be `find().fetch()`.

Comment: @RamilMuratov you don't use fetch() in helpers unless you need to do something else besides returning those documents from the collection so no, you're wrong Ramil.

Answer (score 0):

Luna is correct and you should not do .fetch() as Ramil suggested. You are allowed to return a cursor from a helper and you should do so as it is more performant than returning an Array.